# Can I use the same dust.js module with different partials?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dust.js

I'm trying to use dust.js templating powers to render some html. I've made a model that renders a button and takes as partials the href and the text.

```
{>"modules/Button/Button.tl"/}
        {<button_link}
            some url
        {/button_link}
        {<button_text}
            some text
        {/button_text}
```

The trick is I want this piece of code repeated 3 times because I have 3 different buttons. The issue is that, when rendered Dust fills all the partials with the final href and button. So all 3 buttons will look exactly the same, and that's not what I want.

Can anyone help me? How do I render the same module multiple times.

PS: I could just make a module that renders all 3 buttons at once. But I wanted to reuse that module later on to render a single button in another page. I wanted to dodge this workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a partial (what you're calling "module") that accepts parameters, then you can use the partial as many times as you want, with different values:

```
{>"modules/Button/Button.tl" button_link="some/url" button_text="some text" /}
```

The partial definition would look something like this:

```
<a href=button_link class="button">{button_text}</a>
```

For reference: http://www.dustjs.com/guides/partials/ and http://www.dustjs.com/docs/syntax/#partial